Setting the same axis limits for all *unpacked* subplots
What is an efficient way to assign the same specs (for example, xlim) to matplotlib unpacked subplots?
I have
fig, (axs1, axs2,axs3) = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, figsize=(10,6), gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [2, 1, 1], 'hspace':0})

And I want to cycle over them, or find a common object similar to plt.setp(), to share same specs for all axes, for example to avoid:
axs1.set_xlim(0., 1.)
axs2.set_xlim(0., 1.)
axs3.set_xlim(0., 1.)


sharex=True makes the xlimits the same?

You can use a loop to apply the same specs to all subplots efficiently.
Something like:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, (axs1, axs2, axs3) = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, figsize=(10, 6), 
gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [2, 1, 1], 'hspace': 0})

axes = [axs1, axs2, axs3]

for ax in axes:
    ax.set_xlim(0., 1.)

plt.show()

Or you can use plt.setp():
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (axs1, axs2, axs3) = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, figsize=(10, 6), gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [2, 1, 1], 'hspace': 0})

axes = [axs1, axs2, axs3]

plt.setp(axes, xlim=(0., 1.))

plt.show()


No need for an intermediate variable axes.

It's cleaner, but you can do without intermediate variable :)

cleaner than just using fig.axes in this case?

@tmdavison You're right fig.axes is already great!
